# Catching a middle mouse button click in an Angular 6 directive

Tags: angular

I made a custom directive in which I want to catch middle mouse button click events. I figured it'd just be a normal click event, and to go from there but it's only fired when the left mouse button is clicked.

```
  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick($event){
    console.info('Click event fired', $event);
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Use "mousedown" event, and make use of event callback "button" value:
`element.addEventListener('mousedown', (e)=>{alert(e.button);});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer for 2020**

The "which" attribute from MouseEvent been deprecated. The currently up to date way to figure out which button was clicked is the "button" attribute.

assuming "event" is a "MouseEvent", event.button is a number which can be interpreted as follows:

- 0: Main button pressed, usually the left button or the un-initialized
  state
- 1: Auxiliary button pressed, usually the wheel button or the
  middle button (if present)
- 2: Secondary button pressed, usually the
  right button
- 3: Fourth button, typically the Browser Back button
- 4: Fifth button, typically the Browser Forward button

Adapting from @alex-wiese's answer, and depending on the input device, you'd get:

```
@HostListener('mouseup', ['$event']) onClick($event){
    console.info('Click event fired', $event);
    if($event.button === 1)
       console.info('Middle mouse button clicked');
}
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Answer (score 5):

You need to handle the `mouseup` or `mousedown` event which capture all mouse clicks, rather than just the left button.

```
  @HostListener('mouseup', ['$event']) onClick($event){
    console.info('Click event fired', $event);
    if($event.which === 2)
       console.info('Middle mouse button clicked');
  }
```

The `$event` variable returned will be a [MouseEvent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_which.asp). You can check the `which` property to see which button was pressed. If `$event.which === 2` then it will be the middle mouse button.

[Here is a live example](https://jsfiddle.net/ft9gpoqz/) I created so you can see it in action.

Comment: Thank you. I remember trying mouseup and it didn't work so I tried to see what the issue is. It won't trigger on a button, but will on say a td. Any reason for this behaviour?

Comment: @TimVN hmm it is working for me, can you please check [this new live example](https://jsfiddle.net/cus79wye/) I created using a directive with `<button>`?

Comment: It was because of the order in which I import my modules. I was using it in my entry component, so apparently I had to move up the loading of my directives module. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try mousedown event and catch the middle button click

```
    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event']) onClick(e) {
        console.log(e.which)
        if (e.which === 2) {
          console.log('Middle button ==> ', e.which)
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
```